# Override template for configurable product in cart

Tags: cart, configurable-product

When I added a configurable product into the cart I can edit it which takes me to the following url "{BASE_URL}checkout/cart/configure/id/". Please could I get some guidance on how I can set the template which is being used for this page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This page uses the layout handle `checkout_cart_configure` which in the default template uses.

```
<checkout_cart_configure translate="label">
    <label>Configure Cart Item</label>
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="checkout/cart_item_configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block"></block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_configure>
```

As you can see this simply uses the normal `catalog_product_view` layout handle and then adds a new block. So template wise this will use the same as the normal product page.

The root template is:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

And the product view template is set as:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```